# How to use requestSupplementaryLexiconWithCompletion

Tags: swift, ios8

I am not sure as to how to use the requestSupplementaryLexiconWithCompletion as outlined on [the Apple Developer site here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIInputViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIInputViewController/requestSupplementaryLexiconWithCompletion:).

I have the following function

```
override func requestSupplementaryLexiconWithCompletion(completionHandler: ((UILexicon!) -> Void)!) {
    appleLexicon = UILexicon

}
```

I am just lost as how to get a the UILexicon, then look at the pair values returned. E.g print them to the console to see its output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use it like:

```
func handler(lexicon: UILexicon!)  {

    println(lexicon.description)
}

@IBAction func click(sender: AnyObject) {
    let controller = UIInputViewController()

    controller.requestSupplementaryLexiconWithCompletion(handler)
}
```

Or like:

```
@IBAction func click(sender: AnyObject) {
    let controller = UIInputViewController()

    controller.requestSupplementaryLexiconWithCompletion({
        lexicon in

        println(lexicon.description)

        })
}
```

`click` method is just a `UIButton` tap event handler

Comment: Thanks heaps, that worked!. I have also got it to print out the contents as follows if anyone else wants to do this. 

        `println(lexicon.entries.count)

        for entry in lexicon.entries {

            println("UserInput: " + entry.userInput + " DocumentText: " + entry.documentText)

        }`